# Configure a DNS Server could not configure root hints

Tags: dns, root, configure, hints

I have a problem with my DNS .. I want set my client computer (win xp) to domain, but domain cannot be contacted, on the details, it said, my DNS is not responding. then I type nslookup on server command prompt, it said, RTO and default server unknown. I try to configure DNS server until complete, but when I click finish button there is notification "DNS server wizard could not be configure root hints", anyone can help me ?

Comment: did you set IPv4 to look for DNS automatically

Comment: I cannot set to automatically, cause I set static IP